# принудительное выключение компьютера через с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

есть функция WinExec("shutdown -s -t 0", SW_HIDE);
но она не выключает компьютер сразу а закрывает файлы сначала
или же может не выключить пока запущены приложения
-> Как сделать так что бы компьютер(ноутбук) выключался принудительно???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле, команда котрую Вы выполняете - это `shutdown -s -t 0`, а WinExec - это всего - навсего запускалка консольной команды.

Если написать `shutdown /?` - то Вы увидите множество ключей этой команды. Самым подходящим для того, что Вы хотите сделать является ключик -f - "Force running applications to close without forewarning users. The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is specified for the /t parameter." - то есть, параметр -f *подразумевается*, когда в t указывается значение больше нуля.

Либо -f укажите, либо 0 замените на положительное число.

Еще можно использовать ключик -p - "Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning."

Еще - если это Ваш компьютер - можно установить пакет [sysinternals suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), который добавляет в винду много полезных команд, в частности, [PsShutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown). И у psshutdown есть собственный набор ключей.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант — на компьютере в реестр внести следующее:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1"
"WaitToKillAppTimeout"="5000"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop]
"AutoEndTasks"="1"
"WaitToKillAppTimeout"="5000"
```

Это автоматическое убиение всех задач при выключении, если не выключатся сами в течение 5 секунд.